# how to attendance data from form into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am using this form to show student lists and a radio button/dropdown to place present absent thing, i want to know how to store whole data of students along with attendance into my db

```
<form name="insert-attendance.php" action="insert-attendance.php" method="post">
    <?php
        include('connection.php');
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sc_students WHERE Student_Class='$classname' AND  Student_Section='$section'");
        $result->execute();
        for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuid" value="<?php echo $row['Student_id'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuname" value="<?php echo $row['Student_name'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuclass" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Class'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="section" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Section'] ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="attdate">
                <td>
                    <select name="attndc">
                        <option value="present">PRESENT</option>
                        <option value="absent">ABSENT</option>
                        <option value="leave">LEAVE</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and this is my insert.php file but it doesn't work

```
<?php
    $studentid = $_POST['stuid'];
    $stuname = $_POST['stuname'];
    $stuclass = $_POST['stuclass'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    $attdate = $_POST['attdate'];
    $attndc = $_POST['attndc'];
    include "connection.php";
    $values = "$studentid, $stuname, $stuclass, $section, $attdate, $attndc";
    $sql = array();
    $sql[] = '("' . int($row['student_id']) . '' . mysql_real_escape_string($row['stuclass']) . '", ' . $row['section'] . ', ' . $row['attndc'] . ', ' . $row['attdate'] . ' )';
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO sc_attendance (student_id, class, section, status,attendance_date) VALUES ' . implode(',', $sql);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $db->execute($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use name arrays like `stuid[],stuname[]` to input fields in your html form, right now there will be same name `stuid,stuname` of input fields for all students. In HTML if 2 input fields are having same names then last field will be considered final input field and all other input fields will be discarded (in fact their values are being replaced with the last field). To avoid this replacement of last field you have to use `[]` with name and treat them as arrays once they are into PHP. Here your form will look like:

```
<form name="insert-attendance.php" action="insert-attendance.php" method="post">
    <?php
        include('connection.php');
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sc_students WHERE Student_Class='$classname' AND  Student_Section='$section'");
        $result->execute();
        for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuid[]" value="<?php echo $row['Student_id'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuname[]" value="<?php echo $row['Student_name'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stuclass[]" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Class'] ?>"></input></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="section[]" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Section'] ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="attdate[]">
                <td>
                    <select name="attndc[]">
                        <option value="present">PRESENT</option>
                        <option value="absent">ABSENT</option>
                        <option value="leave">LEAVE</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now in `insert.php` you have to treat input fields as arrays so that you can get data of all students and insert them into database table:

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";
    $total = count($_POST['stuid']);

    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
        $studentid = $_POST['stuid'][$i];
        $stuname = $_POST['stuname'][$i];
        $stuclass = $_POST['stuclass'][$i];
        $section = $_POST['section'][$i];
        $attdate = $_POST['attdate'][$i];
        $attndc = $_POST['attndc'][$i];

        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO sc_attendance (student_id, class, section, status,attendance_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->bind_param($studentid, $stuclass, $section, $attdate, $attndc);
        $db->execute($sql);
    }
?>
```

You have made many errors in your sql statment and query. I have corrected that for you.